# Spoof an Email in Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

The title pretty much describes the question.

Currently, I am using SMTPlib in python 3.6 and my code, shown below, sends an email with the name changed, but the real sending email address is till there. How would I remove that?

```
import smtplib

to = 'toemail@hotmail.co.uk'
gmail_user = 'fromemail@gmail.com'
gmail_pwd = 'pass'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + "Hello World! <test@spam.com>" + '\n' + 'Subject: Test\n'
print(header)
msg = header + '\nSending a test message!\n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
print('done!')
smtpserver.close()
```

Oh, and if there are any better libraries for sending spoof emails, then please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Belongs to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PedroLobito Personally I would say it's more coding related.

Comment: Spoof an email is definitely security related.

Comment: "How do I use this library" would definitely not be accepted on security.SE, regardless of whether you're trying to do a vaguely security-related thing with that library.

Comment: @PedroLobito I completely agree, but I doubt it would be as useful or informative as this one

Comment: Which one is the "real sending email address" and which is the one you want to appear?

Comment: @jwodder the real email is fromemail@gmail.com and the fake one is Hello World! <test@spam.com>

Comment: @Antobat: Then it's likely Gmail is rewriting the message headers to prevent spoofing.  You'll need to use a less security-minded mail server.